# Bitmap return null value in bitmap factory

Tags: android, bitmap

I always have null value for bitmap, this is my code:

```
BitmapFactory.Options myOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
myOptions.InDither = true;
myOptions.InScaled = false;
myOptions.InPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.Argb8888;
myOptions.InPurgeable = true;

Resources Res = ApplicationContext.Resources;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Res, Resource.Id.imageView1, myOption);
```

Comment: Then probably the bitmap would become too big to fit in memory. Try with a smaller picture.

Comment: `DecodeResource(Res, Resource.Id.imageView1,`??? What are you trying to do? An image view is no picture. No resource. Please explain.

Comment: am try with android icon and an image with 284*128 pixel

Comment: no i used image view with resourse in xml         android:src="@drawable/moblielogo"

Comment: Strange code. It should more be like `BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(R.drawable.icon);`.

Comment: `i used image view with resourse in xml `. And you found it not necessary to tell that right away!?

Comment: sorry for that , but i still want to resolve that problem ?@greenapps

Comment: You did not give relevant info when asked. That makes it difficult to help you.